# How to Force File Download on Twisted HTTP Server?

Tags: python, http, url, twisted

Pretty simple question, I am currently wanting for users to download (not open) a csv file that is stored on a python Twisted Web Server. The file currently opens in the browser when accessing its URL.

Comment: You need to set the 'Content-Disposition' in the HTTP header. Not answering, because I have no idea how using twisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set response headers like this:

```
request.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders(
    'Content-Disposition', ['attachment; filename="foo"'])
```

Comment: n00bish question: how could I match requests for specific file extension, say "foo.csv"?

Comment: I don't understand that question.  Possibly you should open a new SO question for it, anyway.

Comment: So, where would I go about placing this statement? I don't have a defined render_GET method for static requests. All I use to handle static requests is setting static.FILe('folder').

Comment: You'll have to subclass `static.File` to add the logic.  There's no support for setting additional arbitrary response headers in a `static.File` instance.  You could file a feature request for some extra APIs on `static.File` for this, though.

Comment: I posted yet another follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958272/subclassing-static-file). I'm having some trouble with a simple subclassing of static.File, I wanted to make it separate question this time. :)